# Set text and value for both td tag and input tag at same time using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set `text` and `value` for both `td` tag and `input` tag at the same time. But after clicking the button, td tag is filled with data and input tag disappears.

What is the best solution for this?

```js
function myfunction() {
  $("#sel").val("Kannan");
  $(".sel").html("Kannan");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sel">
      <input type="text" id="sel">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="myfunction();">click</button>
```

Comment: `$(".sel").html("Kannan");` overwrites the content of  `TD` its Funtioning as designed

Comment: ^ To add to the above, if you want to add content instead of overwrite, use `append()` instead

Comment: prepend() to insert it before the input and append() to insert it after

Comment: Where do you want the text in the cell to appear? Before the input?

Comment: I want to prepend. I tried Rory 's comment and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove unecessary line in your JS

```js
function myfunction() {
  $("#sel").val("Kannan");
  //$(".sel").html("Kannan"); Remove this line.
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="sel">
      <input type="text" id="sel">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button onClick="myfunction();">click</button>
```